# Работа с аудио и видео node JS

Tags: node.js

Запускаю сервер на node JS, почему я не могу воспроизвести видео и аудио на этой странице, видел кусок кода, где в потоке отправлялось видео с сервера. Мой вопрос: как сделать, чтобы видео и аудио все же воспроизводилось. Пишу на Node JS 2 день, ничего годного в интернете не нашел, как реализовать, поэтому уважаемые комментаторы не судите строго)

Есть html страница:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Хоккейная экипировка</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header><div class = "headBlock" id="blink">Хоккейная экипировка</div></header>
    <div class = "buttonPanel">
        <a href="#" class="button25" onclick="location.href='contacts.html';">Контакты</a>
         <a href="#" class="button25" onclick="location.href='galery.html';">Галерея</a>
    </div>
    <div class = "menu"> 
    <div class = "spider"></div>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <th>Главное меню</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr><td onclick="location.href='catalog.html';">Каталог</td></tr>
            <tr><td onclick="location.href='aboutCompany.html';">О компании</tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
    <div class = "centerBlock">
        <div>
            <div>Видео о хоккее</div>
             <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
                   <source src="video/ska.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
                   Тег video не поддерживается вашим браузером. 
            </video>
        </div>
        </br>
        </br>
        <div>
            <div> Музыка о хоккее</div>
                  <audio id="myPlayer" src="audio/music.ogg" controls="controls"></audio><br/><br/>
                  <button onclick="document.getElementById('myPlayer').play()">Играть</button>
                  <button onclick="document.getElementById('myPlayer').pause()">Пауза</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    <a href="#" class="button" onclick = "location.href='index.html';">На главную</a>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Сервер:

```
       var http = require("http");
       var url = require("url");
       var fs  = require('fs');
       var mysql    = require('mysql');
       var path = require('path');
       formidable = require('formidable');

         function onServer(route, newServer, reqtype) {

          function onRequest(request, response){

          var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        try {pathname = pathname.substring(1, pathname.length);} catch (err){}
      if(request.method === 'GET')  get(request, response, pathname);
      if (request.method === 'POST')
            post(request, response, pathname);
    else{
        if (pathname !== "favicon.ico") {
            openPage(response, pathname);
        }
       }
     }

        function openPage(response, pathname){
        var path = route(pathname);
        var html = "";
        html = newServer(path);
        var type = reqtype(path);
        response.writeHead(302, {"Content-Type" : "text/" + type});
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
     }

    function get(request, response, pathname){
    switch(pathname){

    case "audio/music.ogg": 
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'audio/music.ogg');
    var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);
    response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
    });
    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
    readStream.pipe(response);
    break;

    case "video/ska.ogv":
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'video/ska.ogv');
    var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);
    response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'video/ska.ogv',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
    });
    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
    readStream.pipe(response);      
    break;      

      default: console.log("Uncorrect choice");
     }
   }

    function post(request, response, pathname){
    switch(pathname){
    case "registration.html":
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(request, function(err, params, files){           
            connection.query("INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (?,?)", [params["login"],params["userpass"]], function(err, result) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('new registration');
                        openPage(response, "successfulRegistration.html");
                    }
                        else
                        console.log(err.message);
                });
            });
            break;

        case "autorization.html":
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
            form.parse(request, function(err, params, files){
                connection.query('SELECT * from users',  params, function(err, rows, fields){
                    if (!err){
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                            if (rows[i].login === params.login && rows[i].password === params.password){
                                console.log('5');
                                console.log('authorization');
                                openPage(response, "home.html");
                                return 0;
                            }
                            else{
                                openPage(response, "unsuccessfulRegistration.html");
                                return 0;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(params);
                    }
                });
            });
            break;

            case "server.js":
            fs.readFile('txt/company.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
                response.write(data);
                response.end();
            }     
            }); 
            break;

            case "audio/music.ogg":
            var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'audio/music.ogg');
            var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);
            response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
            });
            var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
            readStream.pipe(response);
            break;

            case "video/ska.ogv":
            var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'video/ska.ogv');
            var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);
            response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'video/ska.ogv',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
            });
            var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath);
            readStream.pipe(response);
            break;


      default: console.log("Uncorrect choice");
     }
   }
  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(5656);
  console.log("Server started on port 5656");
 };

 exports.onServer = onServer;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51291/discussion-on-question-by-bsuart2017------node-js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> D:\NodeJS\server.js:48
>   var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'video/ska.ogv');
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Не надо объявлять переменные с именем `path` - они перекрывают модуль.

Comment: мне объяснили схему, как что организовать, вопрос в том, как сделать мой "код" рабочим

Comment: @bsuart2017, подебажить и понять, почему он не работает. Или, хотя бы, сократить его до _минимаольного_ примера. У тебя там даже какие-то обращения к БД есть...

Comment: ошибка: D:\NodeJS\server.js:48
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'video/ska.ogv');
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Comment: @bsuart2017, прекрати объявлять переменные с именем path - они перекрывают модуль.

Comment: @ Qwertiy,проблема решена

Comment: @bsuart2017, вот надо было с самого начала ошибку в вопрос включать. А не мучать людей с неработающим видео. Я думал, видео просто не воспроизводится, но ничего не падает.

Comment: честно не знал, как сформулировать

Comment: @bsuart2017, принимай ответ нажатием на галочку слева. Ответ про видео отправил в отдельный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605311/178988.