# Как сделать минимальный пример с видео на nodejs?

Tags: node.js, html5, видео

Как не подключая сторонних модулей сделать пример http-сервера с видео на странице?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот минимальный пример:

1. Берём два видео со страницы w3c по тегу видео:
   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

   Сами файлы:
   http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4
   http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg
2. Делаем минимальную html-страницу (video-test.html):

   ```
   <!doctype html>

   <title>Test with video</title>

   <video controls>
     <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
   ```
3. Пишем серверный код ($server-video.js):

   ```
   var http = require('http');
   var fs = require('fs');

   http.createServer(function (request, response) {
     var file = decodeURIComponent(request.url.substr(1));
     var headers = {};

     console.log(file);

     switch(file) {
       case "":
       case "video-test.html":
         file = "video-test.html";
         headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
         break;

       case "mov_bbb.mp4":
         headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4';
         break;

       case "mov_bbb.ogg":
         headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/ogg';
         break;

       default:
         response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
         response.end('Not found!');
         return;
     }

     fs.stat(file, function (error, data) {
       if (error) {
         console.log(error);
         response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
         response.end('An error occured while loading file information :(');
       } else if (!data.isFile()) {
         response.writeHead(403, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
         response.end('Not a file');
       } else {
         headers['Content-length'] = data.size;
         response.writeHead(200, headers);
         fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response);
       }
     });
   }).listen(8081);
   ```
4. Запускаем

   ```
   node $server-video.js
   ```
5. Убеждаемся, что видео воспроизводится, не работает только перемотка.
   Пробуем убрать из разметки mp4-версию и видим тот же результат.

---

Почему не работает перемотка?

Вероятно это происходит из-за того, что хром в таком случае хочет видеть поддержку partial-ответов, которую мы не реализовали.