# Как добавить видео на сайт?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильно вставить видео на сайт?
Верстаю макет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего, придётся задействовать HTML и CSS.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/605310/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Видео есть на YouTube**. Нажимаем "Поделиться"->"HTML-код". Затем вставляем его на сайт.
- **Используем `video`** по следующему примеру:

  ```js
  <video src="ссылка" controls></video>
  ```
- **Используем `embed`**. Здесь уже необходимо использовать сторонний медиаплеер, к примеру, Macromedia Flash Player:

  ```js
  <embed src="путь к медиаплееру" width="ширина" height="высота" type="тип объекта" pluginspage="анкор для скачки плагина или дополнения">
  ```