# Воспроизвести аудио с ASP.NET Core сервера во Flutter-приложении

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, flutter

На сервере лежит аудиофайл, который я пытаюсь получить из метода контроллера, возвращающего `ActionResult`, и воспроизвести во Flutter-приложении следующим образом:

```
return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), "audio/mpeg");
```

Для воспроизведения были испробованы библиотеки `flutter_sound` и `audioplayers`. В обоих случаях воспроизведение не начиналось и внятных текстов ошибок тоже выдано не было. Если же я открываю ссылку в браузере, то воспроизведение идет либо загружается файл (в зависимости от того, был ли задан третий параметр в методе `File()`

**UPD**

В приложении воспроизведение запускается следующим образом в результате нажатия на кнопку:

```
await _audioPlayer.play(fileUrl)
```

Также воспроизведение работает, если использовать ссылки на mp3-файлы, а не получать с собственного севера, например, [эту](https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3)

Comment: Проблема Вашего вопроса заключается в том, что я вижу код сервера (который работает), и не вижу Ваших попыток данные с сервера получить (которые, собственно, и не работают). Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример неработающего кода из Вашего Flutter-приложения

Comment: P.S. - `File()` - это не конструктор в данном контексте :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov обновил вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить файл как массив байт (`Uint8List`) и воспроизвести его с помощью метода `.playBytes`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov думал так и сделать в крайнем случае, но там могут быть файлы по 10-20 минут длиной и будет слишком долго ждать их загрузки. Хотелось бы разобраться и все-таки понять, почему не воспроизводится по ссылке

Comment: Я не предлагаю это как конечный вариант) Просто проверка, что AudioPlayer в состоянии воспроизвести ваш файл, полученный в виде массива байт, в принципе. Если да - разбираться, что у него не заладилось с потоком

Comment: @Kir_Antipov он воспроизводит файлы из других источников, в вопросе прикрепил ссылку для примера. В моем случае, судя по отладке, даже не заходит в метод контроллера. Возможно ли, что это, например, из-за ошибки сертификата? Хотя при аналогичном возврате изображений из контроллера такой проблемы нет, т.к. прописал игнорирование ошибок сертификата в приложении

Comment: @Kir_Antipov при первом запуске через массив байтов выдает ошибку E/flutter ( 6398): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Reading static variable '_channel@325020947' during its initialization, но воспроизведение якобы идет, но звука нет

Comment: @Kir_Antipov после нескольких попыток все-таки удалось воспроизвести через массив байтов

Comment: Если не срабатывает отладка в контроллере, значит до него запрос не доходит (Ваш кэп). Но до сервера-то он скорее всего доходит. Нужна поискать в какой мидлвари он застревает.

Comment: @4per как это можно сделать?

Comment: Не знаю как это делается по уму, расскажу как знаю. Добавляете мидлварь в самое начало конвейера. И ставите в ней точку останова. Заодно полезно поставить на наблюдение переменную с содержимым запроса, потому что наловите кучу других ненужных запросов. Дальше "Шагами" выходите из своей мидлвари и шагаете по дальнейшим.

Comment: @mtrfnv мне кажется у вас с форматом что-то, файл определяется как видео

Comment: @MiT почему как видео?

Comment: @mtrfnv определил по метаданным который отдает браузер. Что в **html** он использует тег `video`, что в **информации о странице** написано что это видео.

Comment: @MiT хм, ну в contentType указано audio/mpeg

Comment: @mtrfnv а contentType вы сами указываете?

Comment: @MiT да, вот это возвращаю из контроллера `FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), contentType)`

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что проблема та же, [что и тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605311/178988).

`File` отдаёт данные без поддержки позиционирования, к тому же, он их даже не стримит. Рекомендую попробовать потоковую передачу и добавить поддержку `Range`.

Comment: Но у меня даже не происходит заход в метод контроллера, когда я пытаюсь запустить аудио из приложения. Когда по той же самой ссылке я перехожу в браузере, происходит заход в метод и аудио запускается, правда, действительно, без перемотки. Она появилась, когда я написал таким образом: `FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), contentType); fileStreamResult.EnableRangeProcessing = true;`

Comment: @mtrfnv, возможно надо путь к файлу вместе с доменом указывать в приложении?

Comment: В приложении ссылка верная. Я запускаю отладку, смотрю, какая ссылка пришла с сервера, затем перехожу по ней в браузере. Все работает. Но если я запускаю аудио в приложении, то даже не заходит в контроллер, из которого должно возвращаться аудио

Comment: @mtrfnv, а неправильный https-сертификат не смущает?

Comment: На сервере прописано ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;, в приложении аналогично. Те же изображения загружаются отлично, в браузере также все запускается. Думаете, что библиотеки могут принудительно требовать сертификат?

Comment: Когда сервер запускается локально, то сертификат самоподписанный, но действительный. А эффект тот же